# C# LINQ Query Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I just saw this code snippet on msdn:

```
var studentQuery4 =
    from student in students
    group student by student.Last[0] into studentGroup
    orderby studentGroup.Key
    select studentGroup;
```

What does student.Last[0] mean? What are we grouping by? An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Well we don't know what type `students` is, which makes it very hard to help you. My *guess* is that you're grouping by the first letter of the student's last name, but you've got far, far more information than we have here...

Comment: Please read the explanation of the query in the example prior to the one that you have copied ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397900(v=vs.110).aspx)). It explains the grouping part. If you do the exercises from that page in order, you would see why they are adding a sort here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of information is missing in your question, but here is the answer:

The query groups the students by using the first letter of their last name as the key.

The rest of the documentation can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397900(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the first paragraph of the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384063%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the example cited:

> For example, you can group a sequence of strings according to the first letter in each string.

The query:

```
var studentQuery4 = from student in students
                    group student by student.Last[0] into studentGroup
                    orderby studentGroup.Key
                    select studentGroup;
```

groups students by the first letter of their last name.